# Syntax Error in Internet Explorer for => Sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following script to detect if Developer tools is open or not:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect

It works fine, however in IE11 it gives me syntax error for =>, I checked a lot of other questions and figured that it needs to be converted to a function, so I changed the following line:

```
 window.addEventListener('devtoolschange', event => {
```

to

```
 window.addEventListener('devtoolschange', function(event) {
```

It doesn't give me syntax error on this specific line now, but for the following code, I dont know how to change it completely as it is complex for knowledge to make changes. I would appreciate if someone can fix this code, or if there is any way where IE totally ignores this code, I tried with detecting IE but it still reads code and gives Syntax error, following is the code to be changed as per function() instead of =>, following 2 lines have =>

```
 const emitEvent = (isOpen, orientation) => {
```

and

```
 const main = ({emitEvents = true} = {}) => {
```

below is full code for above lines..

```
const emitEvent = (isOpen, orientation) => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('devtoolschange', {
        detail: {
            isOpen,
            orientation
        }
    }));
};

const main = ({emitEvents = true} = {}) => {
    const widthThreshold = window.outerWidth - window.innerWidth > threshold;
    const heightThreshold = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight > threshold;
    const orientation = widthThreshold ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal';

    if (
        !(heightThreshold && widthThreshold) &&
        ((window.Firebug && window.Firebug.chrome && window.Firebug.chrome.isInitialized) || widthThreshold || heightThreshold)
    ) {
        if ((!devtools.isOpen || devtools.orientation !== orientation) && emitEvents) {
            emitEvent(true, orientation);
        }

        devtools.isOpen = true;
        devtools.orientation = orientation;
    } else {
        if (devtools.isOpen && emitEvents) {
            emitEvent(false, undefined);
        }

        devtools.isOpen = false;
        devtools.orientation = undefined;
    }
};
```

Comment: `function emitEvent (isOpen, orientation) {`

Comment: [Use Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults). That being said, it is generally bad practice to disable the dev-tools, since it gives you a false sense of security. It can always be bypassed and only makes your own life as a developer harder.

Comment: thanks guys, Babel worked :)

Comment: @ivar it can be especially annoying too